# How to add tabs in Salesforce Lightning settings?

Tags: tab-settings

Anyone know how to add tabs in Salesforce lightning settings? I'm sure everyone jumps into creation of tabs in Salesforce application. I want to create tabs in Salesforce settings. Just like Accounts, Contacts in application, I want to create tabs in settings like Object Manager, Users, Workflows etc.

[image: Salesforce Lightning Settings]

Comment: Thank god. It is not allowed. Imagine, this is allowed and you join a new project and setup screen looks totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** add any custom tabs in the Setup screen.

What you see in the Setup area is part of the [New and Improved Setup in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_nav_setup) and is core to the platform and that (at least as of today) there's no way to create custom navigation tabs as you want in the Setup section.

Comment: Thank you Jayant.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension to chrome that allows that. It's called Salesforce Smart Setup Navigation

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-smart-setup-na/pcfcnkkjfmcncimnkdigpkjhagmdkbnj?hl=en&gclid=CjwKCAjw4ayUBhA4EiwATWyBrgoxWW8GDHtyTOb_aJzP7wUCtk470yC13nXMTWgrDXCaT-sxErZxzRoC-yAQAvD_BwE